# How to Pass variable into Css selector in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am selecting element like this

```
selector = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        '#dealType > app-form-select > div > div > div > app-scroll-bar > div > div > button:nth-child(1n+0)')
```

How can i pass variable in nth-child(1n+0)? I neet 0 to be variable

Answer (score 0):

Try [string interpolation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation):

```
number = `0`
string1 = f'#dealType > app-form-select > div > div > div > app-scroll-bar > div > div > button:nth-child(1n+{number})'
selector = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(string1)
```